# Display Excel on the primary monitor

Tags: excel, vba, userform, multiple-monitors

I have a Userform opens automatically when opening an excel file. It has some display problems, as the option buttons disappear when scrolling down the form. this problem only occurs when i have 2 monitors (main and secondary). I noticed these two scenarios:

1. If i open any Excel file and make it full screen in the main screen then close it, then open the userform it works fine!
2. If i open any excel file and move it to the secondary screen then
   close it and open the userform, the problem occurs!

So,my questions is:

Is there any way to force Excel to be opened as full screen in the main screen?

Comment: I guess that you have tried to add Application.WindowState = xlMaximized in your opening event, but I have no clue on how to force it to be in one screen...

Comment: Thanks, see below for the complete answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the `Workbook_Open()` event procedure, and you'll be able to open the workbook in full-screen mode on the primary monitor.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Top = 0
   Application.Left = 0
   Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,
Actually, in case i open the excel file and minimize it and move it to second screen then close it, open it again, it does move it to the main screen but not full screen, so i added:
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
Now it works fine!

Comment: Can we do this also for the UserForm? because I've had the issue some times already

Comment: am doing this for a userform, because i am taking the heigh and width of the application and apply it on the userform, see my final code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that VBA is effected by the dimensions of the last opened Excel file,by dimensions i mean, if it's full screen or normal displayed and in which screen.
The other problem that need to be considered is: if an Excel file was displayed on secondary screen, and this screen is bigger than the primary screen, then Application.Top, Application.Left will not successfully be able to get the application to the main screen, it needs to be displayed as normal first.
My final code to solve my own questions is:

```
Application.Visible = True
Application.WindowsState=xlNormal
Application.Width =100
Application.Height =100
Application.Top = 0
Application.Left = 0
Application.WindowsState =xlMaximized
With UserForm2
.Height=Application.Height
.Width=Application.Width
End With
UserForm2.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
UserForm2.KeepScrollBarsVisible = fmScrollBarsVertical
UserForm2.Zoom = 120
UserForm2.ScrollHeight = (120 * nq) + 120
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
Application.Visible = False
```